# How can I stop responsive background video 'cover' jumping on every page load? (WebKit)

Tags: html, css, safari, html5-video, webkit

I've spent days now trying to fix/work around this infuriating bug which appears to be WebKit/Safari focused (desktop and mobile) and would really appreciate some help figuring out a workaround.

The issue is that no matter what I do, the background video 'jumps' every time the page loads before snapping into place and playing properly.

**Body code**

```
<div class="head home-head section">
    
    <video id="background-video" autoplay preload loop muted playsinline poster="images/poster.jpg">
    <source src="images/hero.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.head {
width: 100%;
height: 80%;
height: 80vh;
min-height: 650px;
text-align: center;
background: #000;
position: relative;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
        
    #background-video {
    width: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 650px;
    height: 80%;
    height: 80vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0.6;
    }
```

I think it may be related to using object-fit: cover but I'm not sure. I've tried using object-fit: fill but it still jumps around, just in a different way and then when it has loaded, the video is squashed depending on viewport width.

I have uploaded the problematic code to this page here: http://royalwells.agency/stackoverflow. Remember this only seems to happen in WebKit so Safari for Mac, or any browser on iOS.

I have even tried overlaying a "loading" div on top of the video and hiding it after a few seconds, but - get this - even if I have this loading div appear for 15 seconds, when it fades out the video STILL jumps for a second before playing.

I spent hours searching the internet for solutions but have found nothing so far and really need to figure out a workaround.

Would be so, so grateful for help on this.

Comment: Have you tried providing `width` and `height` attributes in HTML? For `<img>`, browsers are supposed to reserve the space according to the implied ratio while the source is loading.

Comment: @Andy I've just tried using those attributes on the video tag (tried percentage and fixed values) and it made no difference. I updated the linked page above using `width="100%"` and `height="100%"` bit no dice.

Comment: @Joseph My code isn't the same but I have an identical problem. Did you manage to solve it?  It looks terrible when switching routes/pages.

Comment: Same issue here; did anyone solve it?

Comment: @Joseph Were you able to solve this. Facing the same issue right now...